# Display of datasets

Tags: front-end, dataset

This question is again related to the improper font sizes used in the Windows versions of Mathematica, including version 12.1: Is there a way to change the font size used in the display of Datasets? While I can modify font sizes of most items using style sheets, I don't see a way to do this for Datasets, so they are displayed using ludicrously large (15pt) fonts. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Are you referring to the default format of `Out` or the format of `Dataset`?

Comment: Take a screenshot and show it in your question.

Comment: I am referring to the format of the `Dataset`. I know how to change the format of `Out`, and have done so in my corrected style sheets, but I haven't found out a way to affect the font used to display the `Dataset`s.

Comment: @Pirx please run the command, `SystemInformation["Kernel","ReleaseID"]` and share the exact release id of your kernel. There are several versions of 12.1.0 floating around.

Comment: Kernel Version has nothing to do with this; this is a front end issue, and is not new in 12.1