# Wolfram Desktop 12.1 fonts are inconsistent within various interfaces of the frontend?

Tags: front-end, dataset, windows, fonts

I just installed the Wolfram Desktop 12.1 clean install on windows by first completely uninstalling all previous versions so previous settings don't impact the new installation.

The [new front end](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?v=2835) for version 12.1 is all over the place. Its font sizes are completely ridiculous. At first, I thought bigger fonts can be managed but they are impacting all around.

Suggestion and command templates have smaller font sizes than the rest of the system. Also I can't even see all the columns of the dataset by scrolling all the way to the right (probably because of the extra rounding box around the dataset and huge font sizes).

[image]

---

Another issue found, weird controller placement in Manipulate (By default the `ControlPlacement` is set to `Automatic`, so the font changes are probably causing the `Automatic` algorithm to choose `Left` as the appropriate default):

[image]

---

Another issue found, `WordCloud` again based on the Automatic algorithm is causing overlaps since it is not tuned to consider the font changes in 12.1. (By the way, I have `SetOptions[$FrontEnd,Magnification->72/96]`)

[image]

Comment: This is an extension of my questions here:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216779/modifying-default-magnification-of-documentation and here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/217224/display-of-datasets These issues are due to the fact that Wolfram has fixed its decades-old problem with incorrect scaling of notebooks in Windows, but it failed to fix their style sheets and internal definitions of font sizes to match the new rendering. Give it another 20 years or so and they'll get it right, maybe…

Comment: Or, we could try simply replacing all of the built-in stylesheets in our Windows installation with the ones from the MacOS version, which uses reasonable font sizes. Not that this isn't something that would have been oh so much easier for Wolfram to do in the first place…

Comment: @Pirx are you encountering the Manipulate controller placement issue as well?

Comment: No, I don't see that one. I'm on a QHD screen (high-DPI), which may make a difference. What happens if you use a different StyleSheet (I assume you are using the default one in your example)?

Comment: @Pirx changing stylesheet is not making a difference. Btw are you using Mathematica or Wolfram Desktop?

Comment: I'm using Mathematica. I think Wolfram Desktop uses basically the exact same Frontend, just loading Notebooks from the cloud.

Comment: @Pirx, the Mac and Windows sytlesheets are the same

Comment: @ihojnicki What about Linux fonts? In 12.1 I have "ScreenResolutionCompatibilityMode" set to True (otherwise fonts are too large on my QHD screen), but this makes the autocomplete menu font barely readable: `CurrentValue[{"SystemFonts", "Menu"}]` returns `{FontFamily -> "DejaVu Sans", FontSize -> 9}`. In Mma 12.0 the font size is 12, though. Is there are any trick to change/increase the size in 12.1? Stylesheets and similar methods do not seem to work for me.

Comment: @vsht, all three platforms share the same stylesheets.  On Linux, you can specify a css style for the frontend to use.  Try the suggestion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216602/how-to-increase-the-font-size-in-context-sensitive-autocompletion/216619#comment554072_216619).

Comment: @ihojnicki Thanks! Sorry, I didn't notice the other question, which exactly describes my problem. I'll continue commenting there.

Comment: @ihojnicki: Dear god, you're right, the Mac version of 12.1 does use the same stylesheets as the Windows version, and just like Windows *used to do* it scales notebook content at 4/5 of the correct size, meaning those "15pt fonts" really appear like 12pt fonts, roughly. I really wish Wolfram could get their act together on this.

Comment: What I don't understand is how did all of this messiness with the frontend slip pass the quality assurance team at Wolfram? Wasn't the high dpi on windows, the key feature of 12.1?

Comment: @user13892, the change in scaling was very much intentional.  That is also why the global magnification setting was added to the preferences dialog.  For those that didn't like it...  If you haven't already done so, please report the cropped `Dataset` issue to support.