# How to open files in the same instance of Wolfram Desktop?

Tags: windows

I have just installed version 12.1 and a new default setting is bothering me. Previously when I used to open a notebook file and following that open another one, it used to open in the same instance of Wolfram Desktop rather than creating a new one every time. Is there an option to change it back to this behaviour?

Comment: At a minimum, I would suggest you tell us your OS, and also how do you open your notebooks. (I suspect it's Windows and double-clicking on the file in explorer, respectively, but we don't have to guess).

Comment: @VictorK. yes, it is windows and I open files by double-clicking in the file explorer. Prior to version 12.1, it used to open in the same instance but now every time I click a file it starts another instance to open it in it.

Comment: @user13892, I cannot reproduce that behavior.  Windows 7 or Windows 8/8.1/10?

Comment: @ihojnicki Window 10 1903

Comment: @user13892, the only times I've heard of that happening is when either the FrontEnd was too busy to handle the event, an anti-virus app was getting in the way, or it was being run at a different elevation level. i.e. as Administrator, Protected Mode/Low, etc...

Comment: @ihojnicki Every application gives its user the option to open new files in the same instance or separate instance of the application by default. So where can I find this option in Wolfram Desktop?

Comment: @ihojnicki This new front end though very good looking in the new high dpi on windows is behaving weirdly in many ways. See my other [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218377/wolfram-desktop-12-1-fonts-are-inconsistent-within-various-interfaces-of-the-fro)

Comment: @user13892, opening additional documents in the same instance is the default behavior.

Comment: @ihojnicki I don't what happened but from the past few days, I got the old behaviour back and now when I open additional notebooks, they open in the same instance. Did you guys change anything via paclet update? I also got some cumulative windows updates. Don't know what made the difference!

Comment: @user13892, good.  I'd be surprised if it was a paclet update, since the FrontEnd is not paclet updatable.